# insert into database dinamic values

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i have :

```
<form action='http://www.myadress.com/insert_wallet.php' method='post'>
    <iframe name='hidden-form' src='...' class='hf'></iframe>
 <input type='checkbox' name='pago' value='pago'> <br> </div><div class='tb1_small sc '>
  <input type='checkbox' name='recibo' value='recibo_entregue' > <br></div><div class='tb3_md sc '>
  <input type="hidden" name="id_p" readonly value=" <?php  echo "$events[0]";?> "> 
  <input type='Submit' value='Salvar'>
</form>
```

and my insert_wallet.php :

```
// Get values from form
$pago=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pago"]);
$recibo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["recibo"]);
$id_p=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id_p"]);

// Insert data into mysql

$sql=" UPDATE bruno_wallet SET pago=$pago, recibo=$recibo where id=$id_p " ;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Whats wrong with this? Somehow it doesn't work... I want to update the column with row id `$id_p` the values of row pago e recibo.

Comment: Seriously, upvote a question where OP doesn't know how to use quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this line of code

```
 <input type="hidden" id="id_p" name='id_p'readonly value=" <?php  echo "$events[0]";?> ">
```

Are you sure that you are passing the right value of id_p. You echo the value surrounded by double quotes ""

Not like This

```
<?php  echo "$events[0]";?>
```

Try This

```
<?php  echo $events[0]; ?>
```

Again where do you get the values equating to this variables $events[0] that you are echoing.

Alternatively.

Also make sure that form input as text first to ensure that you can see the echoed values before making it hidden again as per below

```
 <input type="text" id="id_p" name='id_p'readonly value=" <?php  echo $events[0]; ?> ">
```

or you can just pass the id_p values directly from the form input and see if it updates the database via post. Example

```
 <input type="text" id="id_p" name='id_p'readonly value="1234">
```

where 1234 corresponds to the values of id_p being echoed

Finally, if this value you are echoing is not number or integer, you may be vulnerable to XSS Attack. This attack can be circumvented by using `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` functions. Remember Mysql_Connect is depricated as of Gaint Sign Warning. You better start using PDO or Mysqli

Ultimately, your sql update state should look like

```
$sql=" UPDATE bruno_wallet SET pago='$pago', recibo='$recibo' where id='$id_p'" ;
```

If this solve your problem, mark it as correct answer

Comment: sorry nackolusis did not work...maybe becouse my tables are allready there? i just want to update the  pago and recibo columns